# Numpy lexicographic ordering

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to lexicographically sort the following array *a* (get index positions), but, I'm having problems understanding the numpy results:

```
>>> a = np.asarray([[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2]])
>>> np.lexsort(a)
array([0, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3])
```

For instance, I don't understand why `[1, 2, 1]` (`a[:,0]`) is sort-index 0 while `[1, 1, 2]` (`a[:,1]`) is index 5, even thought it should be samller than `[1, 2, 1]`.

Comment: From the docs on `np.lexsort` : `The last key in the sequence is used for the primary sort order, the second-to-last key for the secondary sort order, and so on. `. So, the first row has the *minimum sorting value* and so on until the last row. That's why the order is : first col, then the fifth col and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of significance for keys is opposite to what you expected.
In order to get expected result just flip the matrix upside down

```
>>> np.lexsort(np.flipud(a))
array([1, 4, 0, 2, 5, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.lexsort` gives you the index of the **columns** in lexicographic order, however the order it considers is such that the **last** element in the column has priority over the previous one and so on. That's why in your example column 5 comes before column 1.

`[2,0,2] < [1,1,2]` because `2 = 2` and `0 < 1`.