# numpy inconsistency in sorting? lexsort vs unique

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy.ndarray s of n-dimensional coordinates. Let's stick to n=2 and let us denote with s[i][0] the x coordinate and s[i][1] the y coordinate.
For example:

```
s = np.asarray([[-1.   , 0.  ], [ 0.  ,  0.  ], [ 0.   , 0.5 ], [ 0. ,   0.  ], [-1. ,   0.25]])
print(s)
[[-1.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.5 ]
 [ 0.    0.  ]
 [-1.    0.25]]
```

I want to be able to sort these points lexicographically which can be done with np.lexsort in the following way.

```
print(s[np.lexsort(s.transpose())])
[[-1.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.  ]
 [-1.    0.25]
 [ 0.    0.5 ]]
```

np.lexsort always sorts from the last to first entry, i.e.,

```
(x_1,y_1) <= (x_2,y_2) <=> y_1 < y_2 OR y_1 == y_2 and x_1 <= x_2.
```

There is no option to change the ordering to the following, right?:

```
(x_1,y_1) <= (x_2,y_2) <=> x_1 < x_2 OR x_1 == x_2 and y_1 <= y_2
```

On the other hand, there is the function numpy.unique which returns the sorted unique elements of an array:

```
print(np.unique(s,axis=0))
[[-1.    0.  ]
 [-1.    0.25]
 [ 0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.5 ]]
```

Now the elements are sorted from the first to last index. And there is no option for np.unique to change the ordering.

I need both functions and I need a consistent ordering. Is there a "unique" or lexsort function where I can change the ordering priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one possible solution to the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43825409/10552040

```
s[np.lexsort(np.flipud(s.transpose()))]
```